# android Gradle project sync failure

Tags: android, gradle, project

Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
[Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
[Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the .gradle file, It'll work all nice

In my case It's located in C directory > Users > JohnRao > .gradle